# convert form data using serializeArray() and sending php via .Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

This is my first post. I have searched for other solutions and what I've found only deals with components of this question. Basically this is what I'd like to do:

- Capture form data (tested, working);
- Convert form data using serializeArray() or serialize() (tested both options, working and outputs to console correctly);
- Send this information to the server through Ajax (not working); and
- PHP saves array as a CSV (not yet started).

Bellow is the code I'm using. But first, here are some alternatives I've tried. Usually I get this: **array(0) { }**

- 'dataType' as Json - returns error;
- 'GET', 'POST' and 'REQUEST' - PHP shows empty array;
- use form.serialize() - PHP shows empty array;
- use form.serializeArray() - PHP shows empty array; and
- var_dump($_POST), var_dump($_GET), var_dump($_REQUEST).

  ```
  var serialisedForm = $(form).serializeArray();

  var serialisedData = JSON.stringify(serialisedForm);
  console.log(serialisedData); //working
  console.log(serialisedForm); //working

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "datacapture.php",
      data: {
          serialisedForm, //tested using serialisedData as well
      },
      success: function() {
          window.open('datacapture.php');
      },
      error: function() {
          alert("the form data has not been sent to the server");
      }
  })
  ```

and here is the datacapture.php script I'm using to test the information flow.

```
<?php 

var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

EDIT - and here is a sample form item, reading .text and .name from my settings.json file:

```
<tbody>
                {
                this.props.settings.schemes[0].questions.map((q, i)=> {
                    return <tr><td>{q.text}</td><td><div class="YesNo"><input type="radio" required name={q.name} value="yes">Yes</input><input type="radio" required name={q.name} value="no">No</input></div></td></tr>
                })
                }
            </tbody>
```

Comment: just change data: {
        serialisedForm, //tested using serialisedData as well
    }, to data: serialisedForm

Comment: Thanks, Ranjeet but var dump still returns "array(0) { }"

Comment: Check the request on console, how the parameter will be sent..!

Comment: Can you post your html? what is the form id or class?

Comment: The full .jsx is over 1,000 lines. All working well and tested by outputting to the console. Anyway here is a sample Question reading values from my settings.json file:

Answer (score 0):

just change 1seralisedForm1 to 1seralisedData1 it will return an json object to php which can be seen by doing:

```
echo json_decode($_POST);
```